# Should I remove --no-bootstrap, and --no-self-upgrade options when running certobot-auto automatically?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm developing a program to automatically renew my SSL certificates for my server.

Currently, the command to renew SSL certificates is `/opt/certbot-auto certonly --keep --no-bootstrap --no-self-upgrade --non-interactive --webroot -w /usr/share/nginx/html -d myDomain`.

I'm wandering if I should remove `--no-self-upgrade` options in the command. Because if I don't upgrade `certobot-auto`, I'll get a warning saying `Attempting to parse the version <new_version> renewal configuration file found at XXX with version <old_version> of Certbot. This might not work.`. I'm afraid some day in the future, the program will not be able to renew the SSL certificates on my machine if I don't upgrade certbot-auto.

If I remove `--no-self-upgrade`, should I also remove `--no-bootstrap`? Because new versions of certbot-auto might have different OS dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would recommend removing those flags.

Also, since you're using Nginx, you probably want to use Certbot's built in Nginx support. To do this, run once with just `/opt/certbot-auto --nginx`, and follow the prompts, including saying yes to renewing a certificate even though you already have one. That will save the renewal settings using the Nginx support.

You can then change your cron job to simply `/opt/certbot-auto -q renew`, which will automatically renew all previously issued certificates, and reload Nginx.

Comment: I did certobot --nginx and now My NGXIN server is died and could not get restart.. what could be the problem.. It now says unknown directive "pagespeed" but pagespeed was working just a moment before.